# Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'worker-src' When using client-only Stripe redirect to checkout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments, content-security-policy

So I'm using client-only(JS) Stripe RedirectToCheckout and I have been having no errors which was great. However, I have decided to use VueJS for my web app. So I imported VueJS via CDN and set it up as usual.

I have moved the stripe checkout function to a VueJS method. However, now when I run the stripe checkout. It redirects me as usual and all test payments succeed. But I have the following error in the console:

> Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'worker-src'.

So there are two things I want to know.

1. What is causing this error? - how can I fix it?
2. Will this error be an issue when my stripe checkout goes live. It isn't causing any major errors at the moment. But will it be a security concern or prevent stripe working when live?

shop.html

```
<!-- IMPORT STRIPE AND VueJS HERE -->

<div id="app">
  <button class="button" v-on:click="redirectToCheckout()">Pay £{{total}}</button>
  <div id="error-message"></div>
</div>

<script>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   total: 2.50
  },
  methods: {
    redirectToCheckout() {
      var stripe = Stripe('STRIPE_KEY');
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        items: [

          // Add shipping fee
          {sku: 'sku_HCLoshvlZRCn7S', quantity: 1}
          ],

        successUrl: 'https://your-website.com/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancelUrl: 'https://your-website.com/canceled.html',
      })
      .then(function (result) {
        if (result.error) {
          // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
          // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
          var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
          displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an error for [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/worker-src) and not a part of Stripe Checkout. Likely your Vue setup is [attempting to register and use a worker](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-workers) somewhere. It's very unlikely to have any effect on Checkout at all.